# 504 gateway timeout error while fileuploading c#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, web-config

I'm getting 504 gateway timeout error while uploading huge files for eg 30mb video files. I have made the following settings in web.config but still it doesnot works.

```
<httpRuntime executionTimeout="99999" maxRequestLength="1048576" requestLengthDiskThreshold="80" useFullyQualifiedRedirectUrl="false"
                 minFreeThreads="8" minLocalRequestFreeThreads="4" appRequestQueueLimit="5000" enableKernelOutputCache="true" enableVersionHeader="true"
                 requireRootedSaveAsPath="true" enable="true"
                 shutdownTimeout="90" delayNotificationTimeout="5" waitChangeNotification="0" maxWaitChangeNotification="0" enableHeaderChecking="true"
                 sendCacheControlHeader="true" apartmentThreading="false" />
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure its not some ISP issue, then also try setting this:

```
  <system.webServer>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="104857600" />
```

Comment: No i am not sure wether its an ISP issue...am i going wrong in my <httpruntime> tag

Comment: Just as far as I remember IIS doesnt send 504 when request is too long or there is a timeout uploading data. I would think there is some machine along the way that is down. Could you try experimenting on a local IIS Express instance with those settings?

Comment: actually my apllication is on another server and i am uploading data on other server....so uploading the data takes to much of time....hence i guess the timeout error gets poped up....but after implementing ur solution i am getting a new error now which says This webpage is not available....

Comment: I'm convinced its not your web app's issue but some hardware, proxy or smth else.